# Why doesnt my nav align with other two columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create 3 columns where I have the nav in the left side, article in the middle and then the aside after.

But right now it seems to be ignoring my nav and my "Article" div gets behind it and not next to it. Why is that?

It only happens when the page is in "large mode" and not shrunken down.

This is what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

```css
*, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


 /* The sidenav */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Page content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="sidenav col-lg-1 col-sm-12 order-sm-2 order-lg-1 ">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Clients</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-warning col-lg-10 col-sm-12 order-sm-1 order-lg-2">
                <p>Article</p>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-primary col-lg-1 col-sm-12 order-sm-3 order-lg-3">
                <p>Aside</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't seem to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It does if you pull it up in fullscreen

Comment: I tried full screen. Are you using some ancient browser?

Comment: I see what you mean, that's very strange, I'm using the latest version of Firefox and when running the snippet it looks different from what it looks like on my PC, even though I copy pasted it.

Comment: This is what it looks like on my machine https://i.imgur.com/W6fDANU.png

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `.main` class in your HTML which you have in your CSS. You should wrap your content (except the sidenav) in a div that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* The sidenav */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


/* Page content */

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
}

.main2 {
height: 100%;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
       <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="sidenav">
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          <div class="bg-warning col-lg-10 col-sm-12 order-sm-1 order-lg-2">
            <p>Article</p>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main2">
          <div class="bg-primary col-lg-1 col-sm-12 order-sm-3 order-lg-3">
            <p>Aside</p>
        </div>
        </div> 
        </div>
      </div> 
</body>
</html>
```